# Can't submit the form manually in Javascript when I do document.loginform.submit()

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, form-submit

In the code bellow, if I have the line `hackButton.type='hidden'`,  my form gets submitted (which is what I want), but I don't want to hide the button. What is the alternative that I have? I can't change it to 'submit' or 'button' since they don't work.

```
   var hackButton = document.loginform.submit_login;
   hackButton.type='button';
   var listener = 
   hackButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      //do things here before form submission                    
     hackButton.type='hidden'; 
     setTimeout("document.loginform.submit()", 3000);
   }, true);
```

Comment: what is the end goal that you're trying to achieve here? Why is `hackButton` a hidden input and why can't it be some kind of input/button that causes a form submission? It looks likely that you could do what you need to by add an event listener to the `loginform` submit event, but there may be better ways to do what you want if you can explain the end goal.

Comment: I don't want it to be hidden, but it only works if I make it hidden. If I make it a button, it does not submit the form. I need to do execute some code before the user submits the form, so I'm checking to see when the user clicks on the button, execute my code in the commented out area, and then submit my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `setTimeout("document.loginform.submit", 3000);` or `setTimeout(document.loginform.submit, 3000);` or even  `setTimeout(function() { document.loginform.submit() }, 3000);`

Answer (score 1):

You should change your logic, as forms can also be submitted without *clicking* on the button. You could set a flag:

```
(function() {
    var processed = false;
    var form = document.getElementById('formID');
    form.onsubmit = function() {
        if(!processed) {
            doStuff();
            processed = true;
            form.submit();
            return false;
        }
    };
}());
```

Then use a normal, visible submit button.